# Scope of a variable in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am facing a problem related to the scope of the variables used .

code:

```
   int row_no, upflag, downflag;
        for (int i = count; i > 0; i--)
        {
            asd = ds1.Tables[out_table].Rows[i][59].ToString();
            int com1 = string.Compare(asd, "Upstream");
            int com2 = string.Compare(asd, "Downstream");
            if (com1 == 0 || com2 == 0)
            {
                row_no = i;
                if (com1 == 0)
                    upflag = 1;
                else
                    downflag = 1; 
                break;
            }

        }
        if (upflag == 1)//
        {
            string val1 =  ds1.Tables[out_table].Rows[count][59].ToString();
            string val2 = ds1.Tables[out_table].Rows[(count - 1)][59].ToString();
        }
```

in this code, in the last if(upflag == 1) condition, my VS2010 shows a red line below the upflag and said
use of unassigned local variable 'upflag'.

why is it so? It was perfectly ok in c++ , but here under multiple nested loops/condition, the value assigned to the variable inside the brackets, does not reflect back outside them, even when the variable is declared before the loop.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider what happens if `count == 0`. The body of the `for` loop will not be executed, and no value will be assigned to `upflag`. That's why the compiler said "use of unassigned local variable" - it means it is *possible* that the variable was not assigned.

> It was perfectly ok in c++

No, it wasn't. The compiler might not have complained about it, but it was still *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 0):

> my VS2010 shows a red line below the upflag and said use of unassigned local variable 'upflag'.

That's exactly your problem.  It's unassigned and you're trying to compare it's value.

Initialize it to a value first.

Answer (score 0):

USE:

int row_no = 0; //or any other value like -1

int upflag = 0; //or any other value like -1

int downflag = 0;//or any other value like -1

Because these values need to be initialized first.

Answer (score 0):

upflag is declared but is not assigned a value, and it is not guaranteed to be initialised in the loop, (for example if count is 0 the loop won't hit the upflag assignment).

Try setting upflag = 0 as a default value when you declare it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this that the C# compiler does not allow the use of uninitialized variables. If the compiler detects the use of a variable that might not have been initialized, it generates compilation error.

In C++ it shows the warning message for the same but doesn't prevent the user from compilation.
If you initialise count in the declaration then it will work.